# IonCube php encoder

Tags: php, decode, encoder, ioncube

i have a client that need some php changes, but is scripts are encoded by ioncube
"//004ff
// IONCUBE ENCODER 7.0 EVALUATION
// THIS LICENSE MESSAGE IS ONLY ADDED BY THE EVALUATION ENCODER AND
How can i decode it to change his php files?

Comment: Ask the client to provide you with the unencoded source files.

Comment: I +1'd this, although this does not answer the question.  What if the file in question is abandon-ware from a company that tanked years ago?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678277/ioncube-decryption-in-seconds#answer-16678425

Comment: @Luke OP says a client asked for the changes. If your scenario was true, the OP should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if the IonCube people did their job properly; the whole point of encoding PHP code is to make it unreadable/unmodifiable. You're going to need the originals.

Answer (score -1):

There is no solution for decoding IonCube. And propably you can't modify that code.

Depending to changes you like to do, see if there is any API integration to that Application or a way to extend it

Comment: I had to -1 this, as I just successfully decoded an ion-cube encoded file.  Granted, I had to manually fix about 2 dozen spots by hand, but still...

Comment: Yes look, of course there are some tools also that providing the decode automatically, so the question is, that yes you can have decoding, but if you have to hack the whole system or write code for more than 3 week in order to achive the result, then ok, you cannot. In addition, anything is related to the skill set. If are you a C expert ok, if you just got an IonCube script and you don't have idea what is the IonCube, then again the script it is not decoded.