# ioncube decryption in seconds

Tags: php, ioncube

I'm a php developer and currently searching for software to protect php code. I know there exist obfuscators and encoders (and both).. but it seems that it's possible to "decrypt" code encoded with some software.

So my question is.. if it is possible to decrypt source code produced by major software companies (zend, ioncube, sourceguardian).. why that produts are still on market?

Why these software continues to sell if anyone can (pay to) decrypt everything in seconds?

Btw, i asked this on ioncube forum and my message was.. deleted.

regards.

Comment: Whom do you want to protect your source code *from*? (Asking you as representative of everyone who wants to do this.)

Comment: @deceze: We seem to always find ourselves on the same questions. As for the OP - if you need to *hide* your code, you're doing it wrong. Whilst your code may have sensitive bits, encrypting it will do the opposite of what you want it to do - it'll make your users distrust it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer simply reduces to: because there are dumbasses stupid enough to believe that PHP can be "securely encoded", the same way there are people stupid enough to believe that requiring a serial code for an application automatically makes it secure.

ionCube relies on a pretty simplistic implementation - XOR from start to finish, which is hardly a "security measure". It runs as a VM - and is vulnerable to all VM side-channel attacks in addition to flat-out reverse engineering (one presentation here: https://media.blackhat.com/ad-12/Saher/bh-ad-12-stealing-from-thieves-Saher-slides.pdf ). Will ionCube say so? No. Why? Because it dissuades the large majority of script kiddies.

I am not familiar with sourceguardian, but Zend is built in the same fashion, albeit a bit more secure and harder to beat than ionCube. However, whilst they're not trivial, they're not impossible to beat, either.

The following is taken from the Zend Guard page:

> Encoding is a process where the PHP source code is converted to an intermediate machine readable format.  This format is hard for humans to read and convert back to source code.  As a result it protects your code from **casual** browsing.  This means that if people obtain access to your site's code they will not be able to use that for unintended purposes.

In other words, if your user is not **casually browsing**, this will not hold up. I don't know about you, but I do not know a single non-dev who *casually browses source code* without the purpose of understanding it, and often, breaking it.

The same thing is true of every single DRM method around. However, they're still on the market. Why? Because, whilst they are not perfect, they're *good enough* to dissuade the large majority of people.

The law and final word of this is: **if you build it, expect it to be broken and *plan for it***.

Comment: "a bit more secure ... than ionCube" - 3rd party analysis confirmed the opposite, but certainly any system can potentially be analysed to see what's going on, so tools need to evolve. Dynamic Keys added to ionCube V9 was a leap forward as code could be encrypted with keys that only exist at runtime, created when required by the PHP application itself and preventing existing reverse engineering approaches from working. There's no magic bullet though and tools need to be used appropriately, but they can be beneficial if used correctly and well.

Comment: You do realize you're commenting on a 5 year old question, right? Furthermore, dynamic keys aren't exactly unbreakable either. Instead of your key being a static bit of data, it is now a key generator. It makes it slightly harder to break, but not impossible. The fact that key derivation is left to anybody to implement also potentially leads to weakening on that front as well.

Comment: Dynamic Keys has proven effective thus far as it allows creation of key generators that even if decompiled, may not yield any clue as to what the decryption key is. But your'e right of course, there are always attack vectors. In the physical world, exploring locksport and watching Lock Picking Lawyer has been a revelation!